# scala spark union of empty dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to perform union of two dataframes. One or both of the dataframes can be empty, leading to error

```
Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 0 columns and the second table has 16 columns
```

How can I gracefully perform the empty check on the dataframes. Normal if chain doesn't look "clean"

```
if (df1.isEmpty) {
    res = df2
} else if (df2.isEmpty) {
    res = df1
} else if (df1.isEmpty || df2.isEmpty) {
    // end
} else {
    res = df1.union(df2)
}
```

Comment: Your problem is about the union of tables with different schemas, not about the union of empty tables. I suggest you use `unionByName` with `allowMissingColumns` set to true.

Comment: @vilalabinot I'm using tables with same schema, the error says `first table has 0 columns` indicating its empty

Comment: If you are using the same schema (or at least the same number of columns), then you will not have that error; but regardless, you can just do: `df1.unionByName(df2, true)` and no matter which table is empty and no matter which table has 0 column, the union will happen and all your `if` statements could be removed.